# JQuery register click events for treeview plugin on dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I'm using JQUery treeview plugin to display my data as a tree structure.
The problem is I'm generating my HTML dynamically from the JSON response objects.
This never works as expected. The elements are not getting registered for click events.

If I hardcode the dynamic HTML, I'm able to see the results as expected. I debugged and understood that JQuery registers the click events for existing HTML elements, but not dynamically formed elements. Please let me know how can I register them for click events.

```
function show(jsonResp) {
    //Parsing the JSON response and building HTML on the fly.

    $red = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < treeElements.length; i++) {
        $red = $red + treeElements[i];
    }

    $("#user-records").append($red);
    $("#red").treeview({
        animated: "fast",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true,
        persist: "cookie",
        toggle: function () {
            window.console && console.log("%o was toggled", this);
        }
    });

}
```

This treeview code is calling the functions to expand and collapse as per the user click events. All of these events are getting registered in treeview.js

```
 this.find("div." + CLASSES.hitarea).click( toggler );
```

I debugged in chrome and checked that my new div's are getting registered with the click events. But nothing is happening when I click.

P.S : If I copy the console log of the HTML element generated, and create a different page, it works perfectly. Only problem is when dynamically adding the HTML code. I'm clueless where to register the click events for this newly added dynamic HTML code.

Comment: are you using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to delegate the event to new content, add the code you are using so we can see what the problem may be

Comment: @PatrickEvans Please take a look at code I added.

Comment: Why are you prefixing (some of) your variables with `$`? JavaScript is not PHP.

Comment: where and when are you calling `this.find("div." + CLASSES.hitarea).click( toggler );` also is this inside a jQuery (plugin) function, otherwise `this` will not be a jQuery reference which would not give access to `find` or the rest of the jQuery functions.

Answer (score 2):

Did you this?

```
$(document).on("click", ".selector", function() {
   // your code
});
```

With this code, you can bind events on generated content. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cB8Tf/

Comment: These click events are taken care by treeview plugin. 
this.find("div." + CLASSES.hitarea).click( toggler );
Problem is they are not happening in my case of dynamic HTML

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
this.find("div." + CLASSES.hitarea).click( toggler );
```

to this

```
$(document).on('click', "div." + CLASSES.hitarea, toggler);
```

This will cause all *future* instances of `"div." + CLASSES.hitarea` to respect the click handler you've given.